# #FF88D5E9 is being used in my wpf solution, I want css color for same i.e. #XXYYZZ

Tags: css, wpf, colors

What color notation do WPF uses for giving colors at various places.
Is it CMYK, RGB or something else?

## FF88D5E9

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BlueGradientHeaderColor"    StartPoint="0.51,0" EndPoint="0.5,1"    SpreadMethod="Pad" ColorInterpolationMode="SRgbLinearInterpolation" >
    <GradientStop Color="#FF88D5E9" Offset="0.5" /> </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking at `#AARRGGBB` hex notation:

```
#
AA => Alpha Channel: 0xFF (255)
RR => Red Channel:   0x88 (136)
GG => Green Channel: 0xD5 (213)
BB => Blue Channel:  0xE9 (233)
```

In CSS, this would represent the color `rgba(136, 213, 233, 255)` or simply `#88D5E9` (since the alpha channel is by default full opacity).